# How to visualize an attention mechanism in a classification task?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, keras

I've managed to finish experiments using attention mechanism adopted from [@cbaziotis implementation](https://gist.github.com/cbaziotis/7ef97ccf71cbc14366835198c09809d2) and now i'm confused with the visualization. I don't really understand the heatmap as well. If you guys can explain these to me, it means a lot :

1. What is heatmap? how to read them?
2. What to visualize in an attention mechanism? The weight?
3. The code to visualize an attention mechanism, in conjunction to @cbaziotis' implementation

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a "heat map" is a 2D intensity image, where dark region = "cool" regions, and bright regions = "hot" regions.
In the context of "attention map", the "cool"/dark regions of the map indicates places the net does not attend to while the "hot"/bright" regions are regions the net attends to more.
It is usually implementation dependent, but usually the attention heat map represents attention weights: how to weigh different regions of the input when making a prediction. The "hot" regions have higher weight and thus they contribute more and have more influence on the output prediction.

Comment: so if i want to visualize it, what should be the focus? is it the weight of the attention or the output of the model? any kind of references is highly appreciated. Btw thanks for the answer!