# How to visualize a heatmap in a classification task?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, classification, transformer-model

I am now with a classification task using a ViT-like model. And I am trying to create a heatmap like this.

I have look up the site and found this  but no solution was given. So i am trying to bring it up again. Help me folks! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry the links are missing. [This](https://pic1.zhimg.com/v2-33e37193b9a3a6a17b9de380a1b14c70) is what I am expecting. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005313/how-to-visualize-an-attention-mechanism-in-a-classification-task) is an existing post.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.